# GROUP BY при работе с xml MSSQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, xml, запрос

Имеется XML структура:

```
<main>
    <param1>...</param1>
    <param2>...</param2>
    <param3>...</param3>
</main>
```

Я понимаю, как вытащить параметры по-отдельности или вместе.

```
SELECT    tmpTable.v.value('(main/param1) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)') FROM tmpTable
```

Или же, если мне нужно какое-то условие по значению:

```
SELECT   
   tmpTable.v.value('(main/param1) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
   tmpTable.v.value('(main/param2) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
   tmpTable.v.value('(main/param3) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM tmpTable
WHERE tmpTable.v.value('(main/param3) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = %value%
```

Но вот если использовать `GROUP BY` также через `.value`

```
GROUP BY tmpTable.v.value('(main/param3) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

MSSQL говорит, что нельзя проводить группировку по xml значению.
Как это можно обойти?

Comment: *Как это можно обойти?* Простейший вариант - через CTE.

Comment: @Akina сделал запрос: `WITH test ( p1, p2, p3 ) AS (
 SELECT   
  tmpTable.v.value('(main/param1) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as p1,
  tmpTable.v.value('(main/param2) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as p2,
  tmpTable.v.value('(main/param3) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as p3
 FROM tmpTable
 WHERE tmpTable.v.value('(main/param3) [1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = %value%
)
SELECT p1,p2,p3 FROM test GROUP BY p1`  выдает ошибку: `Столбец "test.p1" недопустим в списке выбора, поскольку он не содержится ни в агрегатной  функции, ни в предложении GROUP BY.`

Comment: А, все понял. Не статические объекты всегда должны быть в `group by`